# query to change the date format in the column

Tags: oracle, plsql, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a report to create but there's a little problem I can't solve because the column(date) I generate has a different value. I use it in a subquery. My question is can I used a format so that I can manage to edit the value of the column? Please see the table below for reference,

My column(date) contains

```
date_columns
2019-06-20T11:09:15.674+00:00
2019-06-20T11:09:15.674+00:00
2019-06-20T11:09:15.674+00:00
2019-06-20T11:09:15.673+00:00
```

Now, my problem is it returned me ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row becaue of that `2019-06-20T11:09:15.673+00:00`. Can I do a format to make it looked like `2019-06-20T11:09:15`?

I tried the query below but nothing changed. It returned me a same error.

`select distinct to_date(substr(dar.last_update_date,1,15),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')`

`select distinct to_date(dar.last_update_date,1,15,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')`

Thanks!

Comment: What is that column's datatype?

Comment: @Littlefoot The datatype for that column is ```date```

Comment: @APC What do you mean by that?

Comment: @APC Yes. The datatype is ```date```. When I tried the to_date it returned me an error ```ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string```

Comment: A column of an actual DATE datatype does not have fractional seconds nor timezones. So whatever it is it is not a date. Query USER_TAB_COLUMNS for that table_name and column_name and see what it really is.

Answer (score 2):

`2019-06-20T11:09:15.673+00:00` appears to be a string of a datetime in [the official XML representation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime). We can turn it into an actual timestamp using `to_timestamp_tz()` and then cast the timestamp to a date:

```
select cast(
          to_timestamp_tz('2019-06-20T11:09:15.673+00:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS:FFTZH:TZM') 
        as date)
from dual;
```

However, I'm not sure how this will resolve the `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` error. This exception occurs when we use a subquery like this …

```
where empno = ( select empno 
                from emp
                where deptno = 30
                and sal > 2300 )
```

… and the subquery returns more than one row because the WHERE clause is too lax. The solution is to fix the subquery's WHERE clause so it returns only one row (or use distinct in the subquery's projection if that's not possible).